# Is there a neater way to insert a space between strings than something like " "?

Tags: c#, string

When I write out a string combined with several strings (i.e. use stringbuilder or concat), I need to insert a space between each string. I'm often doing that like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("a" + " " + "b");
```

Is there a more concise way of doing the above?

Thanks

Comment: more concise than 3 characters?

Comment: Dude, what's so hard about:

    str1 + " " + str2

From your wording it sounds like you want to output a string to a console, so it seems you don't even need a StringBuilder.  Just use concatenation.

Comment: Can we know what do you mean by saying: "When I write out a string...", write out where? Do you really need to use StringBuilder for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method.

```
string test = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", "part1", "part2", "part3");
```

Or in your case:

```
sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", a, b);
```

Comment: Works, but man is this overkill for concatenating two strings around a space.

Comment: sb.AppendFormat. sb.AppendFormat. sb.AppendFormat. sb.AppendFormat. sb.AppendFormat. sb.AppendFormat. sb.AppendFormat. sb.AppendFormat. sb.AppendFormat.

Comment: @leetNightshade: He wrote in his description "several string", that can be 2 or more strings.

Comment: @HABJAN  He also says he's writing out a string, which seems to me he doesn't even need a StringBuilder. He just needs to print(" " + string) after the first string and when he has no more strings just print a new line.  Seems he's doing a lot more work than he needs to for just printing strings.

Comment: @leetNightshade: Yep, you are right i noticed that, but he provided a sample that includes StringBuilder....

Answer (score 6):

It's bizarre how many people just completely ignore the AppendFormat method on StringBuilder:

```
sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", str1, str2);
```

Comment: Such overkill for adding a space!

Comment: @configurator - there are worse answers, and plenty worse questions. ;)

Comment: I didn't say it's a bad answer. It's exactly what the question asked for. I'm just saying, in my opinion, `a + " " + b` is both neater and more readable than `Format("{0} {1}", a, b)`.

Comment: For the record, there is *no* benefit to this. It performs slower and is more typing. I wish the OP would explain the actual problem he's having with `+ " " +` to help justify an answer like this.

Comment: There are _some_ benefits to this, even in the simple cases; it's easily modified, for example if you want to change it to be `"{0} {1}."`. You can put the format string in a resource, in case you're supporting a language where it should be `"{1} {0}"`. But normally this is unnecessary, makes the code less readable and of course doesn't help performance.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [String.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
sb.Append(string.Join(" ", "a", "b"));
```

Note that this creates an intermediary string, which might be undesirable.

---

Less concise, but avoiding intermediary strings, would be something like this:

```
sb.Append("a").Append(' ').Append("b");
```

Comment: +1 for the second suggestion, although the first seems a bit pointless.

Comment: Actually, if you read the question carefully enough, `String.Join` seems like the best answers. "combined with several strings [...] insert a space between each string"

Answer (score 0):

If you're after pure speed and efficient memory use I'd use...

```
sb.Append(str1);
sb.Append(" ");
sb.Append(str2);
```

For ease of reading, the example you give is clearer.

```
sb.Apend(str1+" "+str2);
```

The gain, however, will be negligable unless you're running this 1000s of times in a tight loop, so I'd go for the elegant, easy to read version (i.e. yours)

Answer (score -1):

To literally answer your question of "is there a more concise way?" the answer is simple:

No.

If you want to specify an actual issue you're encountering, some code to illustrate it, then you will likely get more quality answers.