# C# - Add a whitespace between two strings

Tags: c#, uwp

I have code to display a vehicle by its Make and Model.

```
productName.Text = p.Make  + p.Model
```

The above code displays the text as such: "BentleyContinental", how can I make the text display as such "Bentley Continental".

Comment: productName.Text = p.Make  + " " +  p.Model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a neater way to insert a space between strings than something like " "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532738/is-there-a-neater-way-to-insert-a-space-between-strings-than-something-like)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`string.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
productName.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", p.Make, p.Model);
```

Or you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) (if you are on C# 6 or higher):

```
productName.Text = $"{p.Make} {p.Model}";
```

Or you can do just as you have (string concatenation) but add in a space:

```
productName.Text = p.Make + " " + p.Model;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `string.concat` method to concatenate string parts.

```
productName.Text = string.concat(p.Make, " ", p.Model);
```

In general, you use the `string.concat` when you know you'll add less than a dozen parts. More than that, or if you are in a loop, there is more benefits using the `StringBuilder` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
productName.Text = p.Make  + " " + p.Model
```

Just concatenate a space between two words. I think this is the easiest way.